# how to save images on a folder different from the photos folder on ipad using assetslibrary framework

Tags: ios, xcode

i am new in ipad programming. At the moment i am trying to save and retrieve images using the assetslibrary framework. I do not want to save the images to the photos folder or an album of the photos folder, because then i will not have the permission to access them. I am working with ios 5. I do not want to use the uiimagepicker-popovercontroller way to retrieve them. I just want to put the images in a custom folder on ipad and then retrieve them with assets and put them into an array. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Below 2 ways to save images.

Save to general album

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
```

Save to the local APP folder

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3DImage.png"]];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However i am looking for a way how to save images as assets and retrieve them as assets ALAssets using ALAssetsGroup and ALAssetsLibrary. The document directory would be a good place to store them. I do not have the choice to save them to the photos album because i would not have the way to retrieve them due to permissions lack in ios 5. I would appreciate it if you could explain to me how to work with the ALAssetsLibrary framework. Thank you in advance

Comment: APP folder images can be loaded using imageWithContentsOfFile. It is also possible to load images from the Album.